# Object.wait() without spinning in JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, spinlock

I have a component where threads poll certain resources and `System.currentTimeMillis()`; if there are no resources, they go for `Object.wait(1)`, because I know I will wait for at least 1 ms (the resources are replenished when a thread sees new timestamp). However, in JVM the `Object.wait()` causes `ObjectMonitor::TrySpin_VaryDuration`, so the thread is burning CPU when I told it to go to bed.

Is there any way around it (better synchronization primitive with similar semanthics?) but redesign the component so that the threads go for unlimited sleep and only one thread does this busy waiting? Or can I somehow selectively disable it on this object?

**EDIT**: My question is kind of silly. I should really use `Thread.sleep(1)` as the accepted answer says (unless that uses spinlock, too - haven't confirmed), because there's no point in waking the waiting threads up when it's time as they should already wake up by timeout.

Comment: the problem lies with low arguments to `wait`: the implementation may decide to spin-wait instead of yielding. why don't you use a [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for the task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.wait(1)` is the wrong tool for the job. Use [`Thread.sleep(1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) instead.

Comment: Doesn't this still incur bounded waiting?

Comment: The reason for `Object.wait(1)` is that when one thread finds replenishes the resources, it notifies the other threads to wake them up. On the other hand, you're right that these should wake up anyway, as it's time for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use a flag called `-XX:-UseSpinning`

Comment: Thanks, though this is a bit coarse. And not really applicable to modern JVMs:
-XX:-UseSpinning  Enable naive spinning on Java monitor before entering operating system thread synchronizaton code. (Relevant to 1.4.2 and 5.0 only.) [1.4.2, multi-processor Windows platforms: true]